# Duplicate Values in Dictionary When Logging Distances in Photon Fusion

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm developing a multiplayer game in Unity using Photon Fusion.

I have a dictionary, playerDistances:

```
[Networked]
[Capacity(4)] // Sets the fixed capacity of the collection
[UnitySerializeField] // Show this private property in the inspector.
private NetworkDictionary<NetworkString<_32>, float> playerDistances => default;
```

where I record the distance of each player to the finish line. I update these distances in the FixedUpdateNetwork() method

```
Dist=CalculateDistancePercentage();
If (playerDistances.ContainsKey(PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerName"))) {
    // If the player is already in the dictionary, then we should update his distances instead of adding new key pairs
    playerDistances.Set(PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerName"), Dist).
} else {
    // If the player is not already in the dictionary, then we should add a new key-value pair
    playerDistances.Add(PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerName"), Dist).
}
```

and print them when pressing the 'U' key in the Update() method.

```
If (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U))
{
    foreach(var kvp in playerDistances)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{playerDistances.Count}/{playerDistances.Capacity} Key:{kvp.Key} Value:{kvp.Value}").
    }
}
```

this is my CalculateDistancePercentage:

```
private float CalculateDistancePercentage()
{
    //Vector3 closestPointOnBounds = finishCollider.boun ds.ClosestPoint(transform.position).
    float currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,finishObject.transform.position).
    //Debug.Log($"Absolute distance to the finish edge: {currentDistance}").
    return currentDistance.
}
```

However, when I press 'U', it prints duplicate values for different keys

```
2/6 Key:AC Value:69.639
2/6 Key:BBB Value:69.639
2/6 Key:AC Value:22.622
2/6 Key:BBB Value:22.622
```

even though each key (which represents a unique player) should have a different value like this:

```
2/6 Key:AC Value:69.639
2/6 Key:BBB Value:22.622
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not solving your issue but in general: It is enough to use only `Set` as per API `Sets the value for the given key. Will add a new key if the key does not already exist.` so your check is redundant ;)

---

Then it sounds and looks to me like you are not checking for the local authority

=> You run both, the writing of things into the dictionary as well as the     printing locally for both objects.

Further the `playerDistances` seems to be bound to a specific instance of your player objects so you actually have **two** independent dictionaries, one on each player component.

So what happens is for each player you do

```
CalculateDistancePercentage();
```

which always uses the correct according transform's distance

**BUT** then you always store it using

```
PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerName")
```

as key, which no matter which component this runs on will always return the same local name.

---

So my guess is that in the one dictionary let's say on player "AC" you store

```
2/6 Key:AC Value:69.639
```

and since you also run the code on the other client's ("BBB") component in that dictionary you add

```
2/6 Key:AC Value:22.622
```

The same happens on the other client's side where the component on "AC" adds

```
2/6 Key:BBB Value:69.639
```

and the component of "BBB" adds

```
2/6 Key:BBB Value:22.622
```

Now they get synchronized and both dictionaries contain both keys with the different distances.

And again for printing you actually print both independent dictionaries

---

So to solve this (disclaimer: No Photon expert whatsoever, I'm just googling this together) you either do not want to use a dictionary at all, but just synchronize a single float on the respective component itself

```
[Networked] [field: SerializeField] public float distance { get; private set; }
```

and then make sure to only calculate this on the local client

```
if(HasStateAuthority)
{
    distance = CalculateDistancePercentage();
}
```

Or you could make sure you only use one single dictionary for both players - namely one that is associated with the session itself rather than each player - **Custom Session Properties** each player can write to [`SessionInfo`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/fusion/current/class_fusion_1_1_network_runner.html#ad7e3ad7786255c2f226128c98ef8e300).[`UpdateCustomProperties`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/fusion/current/class_fusion_1_1_session_info.html#a9eba8d438598c06e8191f701be0594c5) and read from [`SessionInfo.Properties`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/fusion/current/class_fusion_1_1_session_info.html#a2016d71b68bcad513d7b47f8a8a59e27)

e.g. somewhat like

```
if(HasStateAuthority)
{
    var distance = CalculateDistancePercentage();
    var properties = SessionInfo.Properties;
    properties[PlayerPrefs.GetString("PlayerName")] = distance;
    SessionInfo.UpdateCustomProperties(properties);
}
```

and then for printing

```
if (HasInputAuthority && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U))
{
    var properties = SessionInfo.Properties;
    foreach(var kvp in properties)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Key:{kvp.Key} Value:{kvp.Value}").
    }
}
```

if using more of those properties you might want to add a dedicated prefix to the keys so you know this is about a player distance.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Not only did it help me solve my problem, but it also provided me with a deeper understanding of how Photon Fusion actually operates. This has been incredibly beneficial for our student project. We truly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: By the way, I used the first solve: the Networked Variable